# AJAX performance with loading images

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need some advice on what route to go with.
I'm using the jquery plugin galleriffic (image gallery), and I want to add  a few galleries for a number of subjects  that the user can choose from using AJAX.

My questions:

1. Should I make one gallery and change the  list content?
   Or just put all the  lists on the page and just "show" them when the  subject is pressed by the user?
2. If changing the content of a  list is the better way, should I use javascript to do that or use ASP.NET (c#)?

I should add that the content of a list holds a lot of images for each subject.

Any advice will be great -- I'm pretty much a beginner.

Comment: Where to start!! Hows your javascript vs .NET C#? Who is the gallery being built for? Is this for a customer / employer / own project?

Comment: my own project :) ,my .NET C# is better then my javascript, but i dont mind learning javascript to a deeper level if its the right way to go.

Comment: Do they need to be accessed by mobile users? Or are you just targetting Desktop market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with multiple galleries that you can toggle using Javascript. You may want to have each of these inside an `IFRAME` in case gallerific cant handle multiple instances of itself. Then toggle the `IFRAME` on and off using buttons on the main page.

This is probably the quickest way to get you up and running with most re-usability, you'll get a chance to learn Javascript by the simple fact you'll be implementing gallerific with a .NET backend and have to custom-build the navigation, but wont have to go into the 'deep end' by trying to clean up and re-use the same gallery.

Basically, you load each gallery as the user clicks on it on the main page. Each IFRAME contains 1 gallery with all images for that gallery (unless you have hundreds in which case you want to use paging with 100 thumbnail images per page), all IFRAMES are running concurrently but only 1 is displayed.

Try getting 1 gallery up and running connected to your .NET backend first, then do the navigation later by passing a parameter into the IFRAME src as like this: `mygallery.aspx?name=travel_pics`.

Comment: so you mean i should add all the images to the html and just show the right gallery when it been chosen?